Can small solid bodies emit radiation with wavelength larger than the body itself?
It's known that EM waves cannot pass the aperture with a diameter much smaller than the wavelength. How is it for an opposite situation? If, for example, a solid body is a $100 \ \text{nm}$ sphere, would it still be able to emit - let's say - infrared radiation with wavelength $> 1000 \ \text{nm}$? Or is there a limit to the size? If yes, what is it?
To what extent can properties such as specular/black/white body be applied? I tried to find an answer with "yes" or "no", but no luck. From what I understood, after reading some articles, there should be no strict limit, but I would like to have some clarification. Any help would be much appreciated, be it an answer here or a link to a source.

There's no strict limit. For example, if you have a point particle oscillating back and forth with frequency $f$, it will make radiation of wavelength $\lambda = c/f$, which can be as large as you want. But it won't be very efficient, which is why people usually design antennas to have lengths comparable to the radiation wavelength.

Thanks for the answer. Though I'm still more curious about the situation with the body/object we "can touch"  and it's thermal radiation.

Point defects in solids (e.g. the nitrogen-vacancy complex in diamond) emits at wavelengths much longer than the size of the complex.

Light from at least the microwave range to the gamma range is emitted by individual atoms or the nuclei of atoms, due to energy transitions.

you wrote "It's known that EM waves cannot pass the aperture with a diameter much smaller than the wavelength." At least in classical EM this is not known. Instead, any one wavelength can be radiated 100% from an arbitrary small structure if it is matched properly, see, the Hertz dipole. What it cannot do is to radiate at a finite bandwidth with the same 100% efficiency.

@hyportnex would you agree that the "wavelength" $\lambda$ does not seem to be referring to some physical size of the wave, but rather a metaphor for frequency as in $\lambda = \frac{c}{f}$. Since $E=hf$, $f$ itself seems to be a kind of angular momentum kinetic energy, rather than an actual physical size of the wave?

wavelength is not a metaphor, photons have momenta, $p=\frac{\mathcal E}{c}$ and the de Broglie wavelength is $\lambda = \frac{h}{p}=\frac{hc}{\mathcal E}$

@James why do you think it's a metaphor?

@OfekGillon I am trying to work it out too... Assuming the photon is a point-like particle, it can still have any arbitrarily large wavelength number, right? Suppose this wavelength $\lambda$ is the as big as the sun. But how could anything physical to do with a point-particle of photon be as big as the sun? Thus, I thought that $\lambda$ might be a mathematical description for something else that is physical to the photon...

@James , your initial assumption is wrong, and it comes from a wrong way of teaching what photons are. When you study quantum field theory or quantum electrodynamics, you see that photons do have an actual wave length, just like phonons. It will be more correct thinking about photons as amounts of energy of an EM wave: the EM wave has a frequency and wavelength, but its energy is discrete and if its in the ground state you call it "0 photons" and if it is in the nth excited state you call it "n photons"

@OfekGillon thank you. In QFT, electron energy has 2 degrees of freedoms, its self-energy ($f$ or $m_0$) and its linear momentum $p$, right? I think what bothers me is that the photon seems to have only 1 degree of freedom, its self energy ($f$ or $m_0$), because its linear momentum degree of freedom is taken away by being massless. If $Z$ being a boson can have mass and variable linear momentum, is there a fundamental reason why can't photons have mass and variable linear momentum as well in QFT?

Yes. Atoms and molecules emit electromagnetic radiation that can have a wavelength many orders of magnitude larger than their physical size.
Why should there be a limit? For a fixed speed of light, the wavelength just depends on the frequency of the oscillating charges, not their physical size.

(+1) The de Broglie wavelength of electron is 0.26 nm, but it can emit light of wavelengths up to 121nm. How can a small object produce wavelengths many orders of magnitude larger than itself?

@ProfRob , when one learns in statistical mechanics about black body radiation, one starts with considering a box of length L and counting the degeneracy of each eigen mode of the EM field in the box. The modes of course, do have a upper limit to the wavelength, so it seems there is an actual limit. Why is this approach wrong?

@OfekGillon Radiation does not have to be emitted in a box and "blackbody radiation" is not an emission mechanism. The oscillating electric dipole approximation is precisely that the wavelength of the emitted radiation is much larger than the source.

@ProfRob , of course, that's not what I'm saying. I mean that when dealing with equilibrium considerations, one talk about the different modes energy can go into and start count the modes. the modes themselves have a maximum wavelength

Planck's law of thermal radiation follows real measurements very, very well for macroscopic objects. But this is not necessarily the case for objects of size near or smaller the wavelength of the thermal radiation they're emitting. They may still emit in this range, but it will not follow Planck's law. This paper is an example of this effect.

Already most macroscopic objects do not radiate according to Planck's law, because their reflectivity is not zero (they are not black bodies).

Correct, but that can be accounted for in a simpler manner using emissivity coefficients.

I suspect what you're thinking of is that EM waves cannot resolve an object smaller than about 1/2 wavelength.  What would follow is that an object cannot directionally emit EM waves with wavelengths larger than its size.  But at normal temperatures it would certainly emit thermal radiation with wavelengths orders of magnitude larger than its size. You won't get any 100nm photons at temperatures under 3000K.
